# Theorem: Odd positive integer N is a prime number if ...

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

Is the following theorem well known?

Theorem
Odd positive integer N is a prime number if and only if there is no non-trivial solution for Diophantine equation

$x^2−y^2=N$

(trivial solution: $x=(N+1)/2; y=(N−1)/2)$

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is true and quite clear. Say $p$ is odd and $p = ab$, and $a \geq b > 1$. Solve for $x+y = a$, $x-y = b$. This is possible over the integers since $a$ and $b$ are odd.

Comment: Example. N=47.  There is only trivial solution  x=24; y=23. N- is prime.                                                                                                   N=81  There is non- trivial solution  x=15; y=12. N- is not prime

Comment: @BorisSklyar I'm aware. What are you asking?

Comment: I am asking: Is proposed theorem correct and is it well known?

Comment: @BorisSklyar "I believe this is true and quite clear."